# Installing and configuring postgres on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, postgresql-9.4

I am trying to startup an instance of postgresql-9.4 on my ubuntu 14.04.

When I type psql, the system output below block

```
root@IFID:/etc/apt# psql
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LC_PAPER = "pt_BR.UTF-8",
    LC_ADDRESS = "pt_BR.UTF-8",
    LC_MONETARY = "pt_BR.UTF-8",
    LC_NUMERIC = "pt_BR.UTF-8",
    LC_TELEPHONE = "pt_BR.UTF-8",
    LC_IDENTIFICATION = "pt_BR.UTF-8",
    LC_MEASUREMENT = "pt_BR.UTF-8",
    LC_NAME = "pt_BR.UTF-8",
    LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
root@IFID:/etc/apt#
```

Anyone know what my next step?

Answer (score 0):

try this below

> echo "export LC_ALL=C" >> /root/.bashrc
>
> source /root/.bashrc

Answer (score 0):

Postgresql makes use of several locale environment variables for the different locale categories:

- LC_COLLATE : String sort order
- LC_CTYPE : Character classification (What is a letter? Its upper-case equivalent?)
- LC_MESSAGES : Language of messages
- LC_MONETARY : Formatting of currency amounts
- LC_NUMERIC : Formatting of numbers
- LC_TIME : Formatting of dates and times

The environment variables are consulted in the following order until one is found to be set: LC_ALL, LC_COLLATE (or the variable corresponding to the respective category as listed above), LANG. If none of these environment variables are found to be set then the locale defaults to C.

The first error suggests that the locale doesn't appear to be properly configured on the server.

To generate the Brazilian Portugese locale use this command:

```
sudo locale-gen pt_BR pt_BR.UTF-8
```

Afterwards:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

The last message says the database server isn't running. Restart it using this command:

```
sudo service postgresql restart
```